# How do I create line breaks in a String I loaded from a textfile

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to load a simple text, like:
"first \n second"

My code is :

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"df"];

NSArray* allLines;

if (filePath) {
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    allLines = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"]; //Of course my text is separate with #
}else{
    NSLog(@"%@ didnt load", path);
}
for (int i = 0; i < [allLines count]; i++) {
    [_textArray addObject:(NSString*)allLines[i]];
    NSLog(@"Answer: %@",(NSString*)allLines[i]);
}
```

And I want to get this text on an `UILabel`. But I don't know how I can make this line breaks to work. :S

Comment: First, read the spec for NSString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting `\n` in the text file, put actual newlines in the text file. In other words, put "first" and "second" on two separate lines in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted either of

```
label.text = [allLines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
label.text = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"\n"];
```

But yes, just putting the newlines in the source file works fine too.